# Unable to filter dates in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, linq

I have written the following code

```
 this.downloadData.filter(
      m => new Date(m.LogTime) >= new Date(localStorage.getItem('fromDate')) && new Date(m.LogTime) <= new Date(localStorage.getItem('toDate'))
      );
```

But it never filter data , i need help . Values are shown below:

> localStorage.getItem('fromDate'): Fri Sep 07 2018 09:10:27 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
>
> localStorage.getItem('toDate'): Fri Sep 07 2018 09:30:27 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Array item 1 is below

```
CPUStatus
:
"23"

LogTime
:
"9/7/2018 9:20:15 AM"
MemoryStatus
:
"24"
```

Array item 2 is below

```
CPUStatus
:
"23"
LogTime
:
"9/7/2018 9:02:15 AM"
MemoryStatus
:
""
```

Once after filter when i do  console.log(this.downloadData); I am getting non filtered results.

Ideally it should not show the second array item,
since time i selected Fri Sep 07 2018 09:10:27 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time
and
Fri Sep 07 2018 09:30:27 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
is not in between second array logtime value which is 9/7/2018 9:02:15 AM.

Only first one should show, what i am doing wrong?Why both array items are listing without any filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it myself

```
this.downloadData = this.downloadData.filter(
      m => new Date(m.LogTime) >= new Date(localStorage.getItem('fromDate')) && new Date(m.LogTime) <= new Date(localStorage.getItem('toDate'))
      );
```

Answer (score 1):

Check below logic and let me know

```
  var fDate = Date.parse(localStorage.fromDate); // parse to date object
  var tDate = Date.parse(localStorage.toDate);

  this.downloadData = this.downloadData.filter(
          m => fDate-Date.parse(m.LogTime)<=0 && Date.parse(m.LogTime)-tDate<=0
          );
```

Let me know if its helpful